# Get number of mutual friends in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, left-join, inner-join

I've two tables:

**users**:

```
id | user | fname | sname | photo
1  | Igor | Igor  | Souza | profile.jpg
2  | John | John  | Jhow  | pic.png
3  | Lucas| Lucas | Coll  | photo.jpg
```

**friends**:

```
id | friend1 | friend2 | status
1  | 1       | 3       | 2
2  | 1       | 2       | 2
3  | 3       | 2       | 2
```

In friends table, `status = 2` it means that they are friends and the `friend1` is the user that send the friend request.

To select the friends of user logged, I did (`$userID` corresponds to the user ID profile page accessed):

```
SELECT u.user, u.fname, u.sname, u.photo
FROM friends f
INNER JOIN users u
ON (u.id = f.friend1 AND f.friend1 <> '$userID') OR (u.id = f.friend1 AND f.friend2 <> '$userID')
WHERE (f.friend1 = '$userID' OR f.friend2 = '$userID') AND f.status = 2
```

I want to do a count of mutual friends between the user logged (`$userIDLog`) and the user of profile page accessed (`$userID`). But I have no idea of how to do this, use a `count` in a subquery on `LEFT JOIN`? If yes, how to do the subquery? Obs.: I need users information too (**users**)

Comment: Are you asking, how many friends $userId has in common with each of his friends?

Comment: @e4c5 I'm sorry for the confusion, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's assume $userId = 1 and $userIDLog = 2, now we can find out the logged in user's friends with.

```
SELECT friend2 as f FROM friends where friend1 = 1 
UNION SELECT friend1 as f FROM friends WHERE friend2 =1
```

Similiarly the other users friends are given by

```
SELECT friend2 as f FROM friends where friend1 = 2 
UNION SELECT friend1 as f FROM friends where friend2 =2
```

Now if you join them on f, you have your answer.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
  (SELECT friend2 as f FROM friends where friend1 = 1 
   UNION SELECT friend1 as f FROM friends WHERE friend2 =1) AS a
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT friend2 as f FROM friends where friend1 = 2 
   UNION SELECT friend1 as f FROM friends where friend2 =2 ) AS b
  ON a.f = b.f
```

The only friend they both have in common is 3 and you get the answer count = 1 for this query.

Comment: I can not use my query and just add another `LEFT JOIN` to this count?

Comment: Well mutual friend means If A is friends with B and B is friends with C and B is a mutual friend of A and C. There is no rule for A to be friends with C. If this is not what you are asking, please edit your question again.

Comment: You is right, sorry again... And about use my query and just add another `LEFT JOIN` to do this count?

Comment: but I don't know what your query is supposed to do.

Comment: The query that I posted on my question returns all friends of user profile page accessed. I just want to do the count without redo my current query (adding left join, and so on...)

Comment: But what exactly are you trying to count? If it's not mutual friends, please update your question.

Comment: Yes, is right, count mutual friends. But using my current query, only adding the subquery in the join...

Comment: If I may say so, the problem with your query is that it is too complicated for the task required. For example, there isn't a need to use the 'users' table at all. So what you need to do is to remove some joins instead of add them.

Comment: Yeah, I got it! But this is because I want to get the friends data of user page accessed too (pname, sname, photo...)